# Solr search does not work without field name

Tags: solr

I am trying to perform a search and Solr does not return me any results when I search with default text entry,It works when I mention the field name in the query browser.Ex q contact:Ajay returns the contact But I need to return with only Ajay as search field.Please help.

Comment: Do you want to search for all of the fields? Or just the contact field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the default field defined in the `initParams` section of `solrconfig.xml`. You can update, `df` parameter to the field you want as the default field. Here is the default configuration from **solr 5.2.0**. You can use any field in place of `text`, which is default for all the listed **requestHandler** in the `path`.

```
<initParams path="/update/**,/query,/select,/tvrh,/elevate,/spell">
  <lst name="defaults">
    <str name="df">text</str>
  </lst>
</initParams>
```

If you want to provide search on the all fields of your schema. You need need to create an new field, let say `search_field`, then copy all the fields into it, using `copyField` definition. You the `search_field` in the initParams.

```
<copyField source="field1" dest="search_field"/>
```